# Drupal 8 views watchdog issues

Tags: views

I found a couple of issues with the Drupal 8 integration of watchdog support for views and don't know where to report them. The views watchdog project page only shows issues for the 7.x version.

1. With an exposed filter for the message field, you can't get results for words within an em tag (like a module name). In some cases, even plain text can't be searched for. Example: message is "Starting execution of backup_migrate_cron()." I can search for messages with "execution" but no for "backup_migrate_cron()" or "backup".
2. VBO is not supported for this view type.

Answer (score 0):

Views issues are tracked in the [Core issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/drupal). The VBO issue might make more sense in the VBO module issue queue, since it might need to be accommodated by the module itself.